# ArangoDB managed services

Tags: arangodb

I am doing a research about some needs in a database and I really liked ArangoDB, The only issue is that I couldn't find any managed services or managed hosts for ArangoDB.

For an example in Amazon AWS services the RDS allows us to easily to scale up, without worrying about the clustering and configuration.

Is there any service that can manage this for me, or should I manage this myself?

Answer (score 2):

You may start an arangodb cluster on AWS with Mesosphere DC/OS. The cluster is fully managed and can be scaled as you go.